# How to make a dragable div compatible with touch events

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I have a dragable div inside another div. This works well in PC by mouse events but does not work with touch events in touch devices. How can I edit this code to be compatible with touch events. I insist on editing right this code not to have another touch screen D&D. The code I have is below.

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;

  /* move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;

    //prevent going out of parent div
    let parentElement = elmnt.parentElement;
    if (elmnt.offsetTop < 0) {
      elmnt.style.top = "0px";
      return;
    }
    if (elmnt.offsetTop > (parentElement.offsetHeight - elmnt.offsetHeight) - 2) {
      elmnt.style.top = (parentElement.offsetHeight - elmnt.offsetHeight - 2) + "px";
      return;
    }
    if (elmnt.offsetLeft < 0) {
      elmnt.style.left = "0px";
      return
    }
    if (elmnt.offsetLeft > (parentElement.offsetWidth - elmnt.offsetWidth) - 2) {
      elmnt.style.left = (parentElement.offsetWidth - elmnt.offsetWidth - 2) + "px";
      return;
    }

    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="mydiv"> </div>
</div>
```

I tried replacing `mouse` events with `touch` events But I did not get my expect. I used following events:

```
ontouchcancel   The event occurs when the touch is interrupted
ontouchend  The event occurs when a finger is removed from a touch screen
ontouchmove     The event occurs when a finger is dragged across the screen
ontouchstart    The event occurs when a finger is placed on a touch screen
```

Comment: Please show the failing code instead of the working one. Apart from the question, you're really [thrasing](https://kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/) your browser. Consider to store the dimensions and coordinates of the draggable elements into variables (or rather into objects) instead of retrieving the values from the DOM.

Comment: @Teemu as I said, I replaced mouse events with touch events and div does not move an were. I just dont know how to make this code with compatible with touch the question is this :-) .

Comment: TouchEvent objects differ from the MouseEvent objects. Take a look at [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yj7z0w4/). The example works with mouse and touches. A simplified coordinate getter for both event types is placed in `events` object (`getCoords`). To handle multiple touches, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events